# configure spring4 with hibernate5

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-5.x, abstractmethoderror

I try configure spring version 4.3.1 with hibernate 5 but i have got error when try to create entity manager factory.

My hibernate version 5.0.9.Final"
hibernate validator version "5.2.4.Final"

My dependencies

- hibernate-core 5.0.9.Final
- hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.9.Final
- hibernate-ehcache 5.0.9
- hibernate-validator 5.2.4.Final
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api 1.0.0.Final
- validation-api 1.0.0.GA

this is my configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {

@Value("classpath:hibernate.properties")
private Properties jpaProperties;

@Resource(name = "dataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;

/**
 * Enable exception translation for beans annotated with @Repository
 */
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

/**
 * @see read http://www.springframework.org/docs/reference/transaction.html
 */
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}

/**
 * Build the entity manager with Hibernate as a provider.
 */
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    // We set the persistenceXmlLocation to a different name to make it work on JBoss.
    emf.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/spring-persistence.xml");
    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("myPU");
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    emf.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    return emf;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
}
}
```

and i have got error :

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.xxx.configuration.JpaConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.xxx.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:44)
    at com.xxx.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 18 more
```

But when i change my hibernate version from 5 to 4 everything works fine.

**Resolve:**

The problem was with org.jadira.usertype" "usertype.core" and i have got mismatch with hibernate version 4 and 5.

Comment: Which *exact* hibernate version... Next to that add the dependencies you use.

Comment: Seems like a typical error when you have a mix-mash of Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5 jars on the classpath.

Comment: my hibernate version is 5.0.9.Final and hibernate validator 5.2.4.Final

Comment: Can you show your actual dependencies!l Not the dependencies you think you have, as it looks like you are mixing hibernate versions.

Comment: On which server is the application running?

Comment: Netty, now i resolve the problem was that i have got mix-mash of hibernate 4 and hibernate 5 in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with org.jadira.usertype" "usertype.core" and i have got mismatch with hibernate version 4 and 5 in classpath